# $\omega$-th or $(\omega + 1)$-th when putting odd numbers after even numbers?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinity, ordinals

The following clip is taken from Chapter 4 - *Cantor: Detour through Infinity* (Davis, 2018, p. 56)[2]. When putting odd numbers after even numbers, what should the index for the first odd number ($1$ in the sequence) be, $\omega$-th or $(\omega + 1)$-th? Davis put the former, but I found the latter elsewhere on the Internet ([e.g.](https://qr.ae/psTh0O)). I am confused. Could you help?

[image]

*Reference*

- Davis, M. (2018). The universal computer: the road from Leibniz to Turing. CRC Press.

Comment: I would call it the $\omega$-th, to conform to the ordinal in $\omega+\omega$ it’d be assigned to but then I’d need to call the first one the $0$-th (and I might).

Comment: The convention I use, which I believe is the standard. one, is that, in your ordering, $1$ is the $\omega^\text{th}$ element. (I'd also include $0$ as the $0^\text{th}$ element.)

Comment: Can you give an example of someone who would describe $1$ as the $(\omega + 1)$th element here? Or as having rank $\omega + 1$? I would find that a bit surprising - perhaps what you've seen is people saying that $\{2, 4, 6, \dotsc, 1\}$ in this ordering would have order-type $\omega + 1$, or something to that effect?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, then where is $\aleph_0$-th, before the $\omega$-th element in the elipses?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, I just added an example, it is similar to the one you put.

Comment: @Yif $\aleph_0$ is a cardinal, not an ordinal (though it coincides with $\omega$ in the usual convention of defining cardinals as the least ordinal of that size).

Comment: OK, what you've linked is the sort of thing I thought, indeed. In particular, what you have linked does not contradict the image in your post, and the difference is not due to any choice of convention, in my opinion. If a well-ordered set has a largest element of rank $\alpha$, then the order type of the set will be $\alpha + 1$. This isn't contradictory, it's just a case of "rank of largest element" and "order type" being different things. These sorts of "off-by-one" discrepancies crop up in a few places in set theory, another being with $V_\alpha$ not containing $\alpha$ and so on..

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, do you mind expand you comment to an answer to elaborate on this key difference you mentioned.

Comment: @Yif, I'm not sure I have a great deal more to say, I'm afraid! Do you appreciate what I mean when I say that there's no contradiction, because they're talking about different things? If you'd like to really understand what "rank" and "order type" means, the best way to do that is to learn a little bit of logic and set theory, eg from a book, IMO. To understand them requires a lot of background which I don't think would make sense for me to try and convey in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinals probably shouldn't be used as an index to reference the individual elements of some well-ordered set, especially not $\omega$ which is a limit ordinal (as opposed to a successor ordinal or zero).

The order type of the even numbers as listed is $\omega$ and the order type of the even numbers followed by "1" as above is $\omega+1$.

One convention would be to index an element by the ordinal of the rest of the well-ordered set preceding it, which would give "1" the index $\omega$ but would then give the least element "2" the index $0$ instead of $1$.